# LDAP Filter for Members Of a Group

Tags: ldap-query

I'm attempting to run an LDAP filter to return all users within a group. Pretty simple, and there are hundreds of Stack Overflow questions which already provide example queries. However the one I'm using is basic, and returns nothing when run in Powershell.

**What I've Tried**

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person)(memberOf=CN=MyGroup,OU=Users,DC=MyDomain,DC=com))"
```

I've also tried "CN=Users" instead of "OU=Users

**Where "MyGroup" is located in the OU:**

> "MyDomain" *(Forest)* > "Users" *(OU)* > "MyGroup" *(CN)*

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, and why none of the 100-200 members of the "MyGroup" are being returned?

Comment: Do the users have the `memberOf` attribute or are they just listed as `member` in the group?

Comment: Well according to ADSI I cannot see a MemberOf attribute. But I thought it is normal for it not to show up in ADSI Edit or on the "Attribute Editor" tab in ADUC, since it's a back link. Am I not correct?

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Active Directory?  Get the FQN of the User OU and the Group you are trying to locate users. Groups are usually in cn=groups,dc=example,dc=com

Comment: Yes it is MS AD. In this case I'm looking for a group which is located inside the "Users" OU: "MyDomain" (Forest) > "Users" (OU) > "MyGroup" (CN)
hence
CN=MyGroup,OU=Users,DC=MyDomain,DC=com

Answer (score 0):

Cross-post: https://serverfault.com/q/978336/536173

TL;DR of the [most upvoted answer](https://serverfault.com/a/978340/536173):

Use `(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=<GROUP_DN>)` to query for group memberships recursively.